# Añadir producto al carrito con cart drawer sin refrescar pagina

Tags: javascript, shopify

Tengo un boton de añadir producto al carrito en una tienda de shopify, este boton no viene por defecto en las collections de shopify , por eso se añade con este codigo.

una vez que se presiona el boton, este añade al producto , pero se va a la pagina de carrito, pero yo necesito que se añada sin refrescar la página y que tampoco se vaya a la pagina donde se despliega el carrito. Basicamente necesito que se añada pero que no se salga de la página.

```
 <form action="/cart/add" onsubmit="addCart()" id="CartForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{liquidObject.variants[0].id}}"/>
    <button type="submit" name="add" id="purchase" class="btn">
          {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
    </button>
</form>
```

he añadido esta función, pero no se como completarla para hacer ese efecto.

```
$('#CartForm').submit(e) => {
e.preventDefault();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes hacer con el api de ajax, cart.js. esta es la documentación oficial:
https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart

```css
          $('#CartForm').click(function(event){
                          jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
                            items: [
                              {
                                id: 123, <--Id de producto que quieres añadir
                                quantity: 1,
                                properties: {
                                      'Producto': '{{ product.title }}' ,
                                    }

                              }

                            ],

                            dataType: 'json', 
                            success: function (data) { 
                            console.log("Agregado");
                            } 

                            });
                            
                  });
```